# TIme Triggered Azure function shows Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storageb error

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage-account

While working on azure functions, I added one more azure function in my existing azure function app.

The function is the only time triggered function in my function app (V1).

Yet before the timer function, I didn't add any reference to storage account in any earlier deployments.

While I try to run the timer based function online, I get the error as below:

```
The listener for function 'function1' was unable to start. mscorlib: One or more errors occurred. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

I googled up and got solutions mentioning to add 'AzureWebJobsStorage' key in application settings and connection string. But got no luck.

Can anyone tell What Can be done?

Comment: The settings should be `AzureWebJobsStorage`, try this again.

Comment: Did that too.. but didn't work.

Comment: Go to kudu site check the if there is any exception. `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host`

Comment: Can it work on local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recheck the firewall and network settings at storage account level. It seems like your firewall settings are restricting the func app to access the storage account

Comment: It seems this is the main issue. If i turn of restrictions over storage account, I'm not getting the error.

Comment: @MaulikModi Congratulations, you have solved the problem. I am curious whether you are running locally or on Azure. I have encountered many similar problems and are summarizing them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storage emulator locally, add `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` as the value to `AzureWebJobsStorage`, the local.settings.json will be like this:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    }
}
```

If you want to use the Storage on portal, go to portal to get the Storage Connecting String:

[image]

And then add the Connecting String to `AzureWebJobsStorage`.

---

If you test the timetrigger on local and still can't not work with the above solution, please try to copy the same code to a different location. That maybe work.

**Do you run on local? Or run on portal?
Providing more information helps to resolve this issue.**

---

Another possibility, please check your firewall and network settings.Suggestion from @Varun05. Hope it help.

Comment: If storage account connectionstring is correct then check the firewall and network settings of the storage account. It seems your storage account firewall settings are restriction the  function app

Comment: @Varun05 Please notice that Maulik Modi's problem is `listener for function 'function1' was unable to start.`. If it is about the firewall, it should return `function host unable to start.`. This is my point. Have you encountered a similar situation before?

Comment: Listener is unable to access the storage account. By creating a new  POC project in C# to access the storage account eg. Create dynamic  container in the blob storage  using c# . He should get some access error.